# Using information from multiple tables in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get this SQL statement to work and I can't seem to get it to display the information im asking for. The error I get is that SQL command is not properly ended at line where select brand_name from lg brand.

```
SELECT CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_STREET, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_ZIP
FROM LGCUSTOMER 
SELECT BRAND_NAME FROM LGBRAND
WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST'
SELECT INV_DATE FROM LGINVOICE
WHERE INV_DATE BETWEEN '2011-15-07' AND '2011-31-07'
ORDER BY CUST_STATE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;
```

Comment: You have multiple SQL statements are u expecting multiple resultsets?

Comment: No, the output shows a table with only the stuff from the LGCUSTOMER table that meets the other conditions

Answer (score 0):

Are you running MS SQL or MySQL?

If this is MySQL, then you need to end each individual statement with a semicolon like:

```
SELECT CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_STREET, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_ZIP
FROM LGCUSTOMER;
SELECT BRAND_NAME FROM LGBRAND
WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST';
SELECT INV_DATE FROM LGINVOICE
WHERE INV_DATE BETWEEN '2011-15-07' AND '2011-31-07'
ORDER BY CUST_STATE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;
```

**Edit:** I see that the question is tagged to MS SQL, but the error smells like MySQL to me.

Comment: I'm using oracle sql developer if that makes a difference

Comment: Sorry, it's not my wheelhouse, then.  MS SQL or MySQL I could help with.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you want to achieve. But to me it looks like you have different queries, so execute them one after the other and seperate them by a semicolon:

```
SELECT CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_STREET, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_ZIP
FROM LGCUSTOMER
ORDER BY CUST_STATE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;

SELECT BRAND_NAME FROM LGBRAND;
WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST';

SELECT INV_DATE FROM LGINVOICE
WHERE INV_DATE BETWEEN '2011-15-07' AND '2011-31-07';
```

If you want all your conditions in one query, use:

```
SELECT a.CUST_FNAME, a.CUST_LNAME, a.CUST_STREET, a.CUST_CITY, a.CUST_STATE, a.CUST_ZIP,
  b.BRAND_NAME,
  c.INV_DATE
FROM LGCUSTOMER a, LGBRAND b, LGINVOICE c
WHERE b.BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST'
AND c.INV_DATE BETWEEN '2011-15-07' AND '2011-31-07'
ORDER BY a.CUST_STATE, a.CUST_LNAME, a.CUST_FNAME;
```